# Roaming Profile Control

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012, windows-8, roaming-profile

I noticed that with Roaming Profiles enabled that even applications have been roaming. Is this normal? Is there a way to keep applications from roaming? I like how Firefox bookmarks move from machine to machine(does cache move as well???) as it is a great way to remain in-sync but I do not like how every application is moved.

I always thought that Roaming Profiles kept just the USERDIR in motion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "applications have been roaming" I *think* you're saying that EXEs stored in the portion of the user's profile that is "Roaming" are being copied to the server and back down to client computers when the user logs-on.  (Hopefully I'm understanding what you're saying. If not, please let me know and I'll edit accordingly.)

This is normal behavior. Roaming user profiles aren't much more than a convoluted and glorified file copying mechanism. If EXEs end up in the roaming portion of a user's profile then they'll be copied.

You can use [Group Policy to exclude folders from roaming](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/814592). (That article references Windows Server 2003 but those particular settings work on all current versions of Windows.)

Comment: Cache and temporary directories are typically not roamed since they reside in the `%LOCALAPPDATA%` part of the profile, which is excluded from roaming by default. Applications which save settings in `%APPDATA%` or in the registry will receive these settings with the roaming profile everywhere the user logs on. The very idea of roaming profiles is to enable the user to log on on ***any*** domain machine and present roughly the same environment.

Comment: What I noticed was some how utorrent was copied over and ended up in the start menu and I never installed it on that machine. This is a default GPO setup.